# Disabling SPA at porlet level

Tags: liferay-7

I have an WAR style application that has been converted from Liferay 6.2 to 7.1. it needs to have SPA turned off and has been tested successfully when turning off SPA at the portal level but would like to turn off at the portlet level.

have tried adding the false property to the  object in liferay-portlet.xml but the app doesn't load into Liferay correctly after that and complains.

this appears to be the recommended approach from https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-0/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/automatic-single-page-applications. there may be some "order" necessary to these properties? I can't determine exactly what that might be from this DTD https://docs.liferay.com/ce/portal/7.1-latest/definitions/liferay-portlet-app_7_1_0.dtd.html#single-page-application.

a further inspection of the error message that occurs when the portlet is loading provides help that indicates the properties order that should appear in the liferay-portlet.xml. I'm able to deploy the portlet without error now.

unfortunately, the portlet still does not act properly. its an EXTJs front end and there are consistent "The schema can only be reconfigured once" and "duplicate object" errors reported in the browser console. reloading the entire page works fine.

how might one start to debug this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I disabled SPA in a WAR application by setting `<single-page-application>` to false in liferay-portlet.xml

See: https://github.com/jorgediaz-lr/index-checker/blob/master/docroot/WEB-INF/liferay-portlet.xml#L18

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>index_checker</portlet-name>
    <icon>/icon.png</icon>
    <configuration-action-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.DefaultConfigurationAction</configuration-action-class>
    <control-panel-entry-category>
        apps
    </control-panel-entry-category>
    <control-panel-entry-weight>1.5</control-panel-entry-weight>
    <control-panel-entry-class>
        jorgediazest.indexchecker.portlet.IndexCheckerControlPanelEntry
    </control-panel-entry-class>
    <preferences-company-wide>true</preferences-company-wide>
    <preferences-unique-per-layout>false</preferences-unique-per-layout>
    <single-page-application>false</single-page-application>
    <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
    <footer-portlet-javascript>
        /js/main.js
    </footer-portlet-javascript>
    <css-class-wrapper>index_checker-portlet</css-class-wrapper>
</portlet>
```

If that setting is not working to you and causes errors, please copy your log traces with the problems.

Comment: thanks so much for this insight. I've since had more developments and have updated my question.